# Adding jquery plugin to joomla 2

Tags: jquery-plugins, joomla2.5

I am trying to add a country selector to the front page of my site for the users to be able to select a country and land on a specific page. I have not been able to find a Joomla extension for this, but I found a jquery plugin that does this, but I am not sure how to or is there a way to add this to my Joomla site.

[The jquery plugin](http://baymard.com/labs/country-selector)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do that:

1. http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jquery-easy
   Install a plugin to include jQuery in

b. http://dabrook.org/blog/two-ways-to-include-jquery-in-your-document
  Do that for joomla template file (don't forget jQuery.NoConflict())

And at the and modify article with that country picker (put JS code in).

OR

Develop a plugin to do all that. (for more experienced user)